# Pre-populate file_field RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, parameters

The site has a functionality for pre-filling forms on the link.

My code to fill text_fields works well.

***View 1st:***

```
= link_to 'Finish creating', 
           create_new_post_path(expired_date: @expired_date
                                title: @title, location: @location, 
                                description: @description)
```

***Controller 1st:***

```
@title = 'Some text'
@location = 'Some location'
@description = 'Some description'
@expired_date = 'Some date'
```

***View 2nd:***

```
...
f.text_field :title, value: @title.present? ? @title : ' '
f.text_field :location, value: @location.present? ? @location : ' '
...
f.file_field :image (?)
...
```

***Controller 2nd:***

```
def new
    @title = params[:title]
    @location = params[:location]
    @description = params[:description]
    @expired_date = params[:expired_date]
    ...
end
```

But how to do the same for the picture?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do the same for the image field. Instead, if the image has already been added, you can display the image with the image_tag above or below the image field.

```
<% if post.picture.attached? %>
  <%= image_tag post.picture %>
<% end %>
<%= f.file_field :picture %>
```

Comment: But in this case, the picture will not be sent along with the form.

Comment: If you don't add new picture, the picture parameter will not be sent to controller. In this case, the picture will not change. If you select a new picture in the form, the picture will be updated.

Comment: But I need that when you click the link with View 1st, the user opens a pre-filled form with the desired image. This picture should be sent to the controller.